# Can I "play higher rated songs more often" in iTunes 11?

Tags: windows, playlist, ratings, itunes

After upgrading to iTunes 11, I miss the "Play higher rated songs more often" feature available in iTunes DJ from previous versions. Is there a simple way to restore this feature? I used to use a complex series of smart playlists like [The Ultimate Smart iTunes Playlist](http://equivocality.com/2011/01/31/the-ultimate-smart-itunes-playlist/) before this feature came around. I suppose I could do that again, but I'd rather have something simpler.

Comment: I think the only way to do it is to use smart playlists.

Comment: They took this feature away as punishment because nobody was using Ping. :(

Answer (score 1):

One not very simple way:

1. create smart playlists for various ratings.
2. Create a simple playlist.
3. Drag and drop the smart playlist into the simple playlist.  Drag the 5* list 5 times, the 4 star list 4 times, and the 3 star list three times.

This will NOT automatically update the simple playlist.